# Import text file as a matrix in a matlab script

Tags: matlab, import, io

Hi everybody I need to automaticly import certain text files stored in my computer as matrices when I run my script in matlab. How do I do that? Thanks

Comment: Start reading here http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/import-numeric-data-from-a-text-file.html

Comment: I actually think this is a question where many readers are interested in. Except it should be formulated like: where to get started or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the question shows little effort I am reminded how I started out with no knowledge about input or output whatsoever, it is a quite dense forest of information really.

Basically to read a file you need to:

1. Open the file
2. Read the file and assign it to a variable
3. Close the file

Some functions in MatLab take care of all three steps:

- [importdata](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/importdata.html)
- [csvread](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/csvread.html)
- [dlmread](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/dlmread.html)

The functions above are suitable if you have very neat and uniform data. Click the links to read if they are suitable for you. If your data is less uniform, e.g. it contains both numbers and letters, you might want to consider [textscan](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html).

Using textscan you must carry out all three steps yourself. First open your file and create a link to your file called a file ID (FID):

```
FID = fopen('mytextfile.txt')
```

Next you define a format specifier which describes a single line of data (a row).

```
formatSpec = '%f %f %f %f %s'
```

This format specifier represents 4 decimal numbers (floats) followed by a string all seperated by whitespace. For more information on the format specifier see:

http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html#inputarg_formatSpec

Now you can read your text file by calling:

```
C = textscan(FID,formatSpec);
```

Which stores each column in a cell in C. So the first column is C{1}, the second C{2}, etc.

Finally make sure you close your file by using the file id:

```
fclose(FID);
```

Good luck!